# Python - Zero length field name in format

Tags: python, centos

I'm using Python on my Centos machine and when I try to run my program I have this error displayed :

```
Running setup.py egg_info for package pyepr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/pyepr/setup.py", line 68, in <module>
    print('using EPR C API sources at "{}"'.format(eprsrcdir))
ValueError: zero length field name in format
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/pyepr/setup.py", line 68, in <module>

print('using EPR C API sources at "{}"'.format(eprsrcdir))

ValueError: zero length field name in format
```

I have already checked the other questions about this subject and I already installed Python 2.7.6 and set it as my default configuration as shown below....

```
 $ python -V
 Python 2.7.6
```

Something must have gone wrong, but I don't know what.

Anybody has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Your script definitely is executed with an older version of python than 2.7.6.

Comment: Are you running `python setup.py install` or are you using `pip` or `easy_install`? If you're using `pip` or `easy_install`, they might not be using the correct version of python.

Comment: Try `import sys; print(sys.version)` within the script to determine the actual version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error can only be raised if you run that code with Python 2.6 or older.  In those versions, you must explicitly number the format fields for `str.format` (starting at `0`):

```
print('using EPR C API sources at "{0}"'.format(eprsrcdir))
```

Of course, this is only a temporary fix.  It would be better to investigate why your code is not being run with Python 2.7 in the first place and then fix that instead.

Comment: The problem is coming when i'm installing the pyepr library, and its setup.py launches itself, since it failed, the download is aborted and I can't fix anything.. So yes, I'll try to find out why it's not running with Python 2.7 while it seems to be the default one.

Answer (score -1):

If you run an install using sudo, you are going to end up using the sudo path's Python interpreter. Not sure if you are using sudo or not for installing, but there is a good chance you are.

Comment: OP said he was using centOS right? So the backbone of yum is Python 2.6. If he types sudo <command> he is going to be using the sudo env path and not the standard user path, or even the root path for that matter, he will be using the sudo path /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin which is going to find python 2.6 before it ever finds python 2.7 and then any installation code written for 2.7 is not going to work.